# Counting multiple letter groups in a string

Tags: python, string, function, count

I've been trying to adapt my python function to count groups of letters instead of single letters and I'm having a bit of trouble. Here's the code I have to count individual letters:

```
my_seq = "CTAAAGTCAACCTTCGGTTGACCTTGAAAGGGCCTTGGGAACCTTCGGTTGACCTTGAGGGTTCCCTAAGGGTT"

def count_letters(str):
    counts = {}
    for c in str:
        if c in counts:
            counts[c]+=1
        else:
            counts[c]=1
    return counts

counts = count_letters(my_seq)
print(counts)
```

The function currently spits out counts for each individual letter. Right now it prints this:

```
{'C': 23, 'T': 30, 'G': 30, 'A': 20}
```

Ideally, I'd like it to print something like this:

```
{'CTA': 2, 'TAG': 3, 'CGC': 1, 'GAG': 2 ... }
```

I'm very new to python and this is proving to be difficult.

Comment: Where is the list of words you want to count for it?

Comment: @IronFist I just want to count all 3-letter groups. Is there a way to have the code do that without defining the specific groups?

Comment: Just to spell this out for our friend the search engine, this is looking for a sliding window over all subsequences of length _n_ (where in this case n=3).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done pretty quickly using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

```
from collections import Counter

s = "CTAACAAC"

def chunk_string(s, n):
    return [s[i:i+n] for i in range(len(s)-n+1)]

counter = Counter(chunk_string(s, 3))
# Counter({'AAC': 2, 'ACA': 1, 'CAA': 1, 'CTA': 1, 'TAA': 1})
```

---

**Edit:** To elaborate on `chunk_string`:

It takes a string `s` and a chunk size `n` as arguments. Each `s[i:i+n]` is a slice of the string that is `n` characters long. The loop iterates over the valid indices where the string can be sliced (`0` to `len(s)-n`). All of these slices are then grouped in a list comprehension. An equivalent method is:

```
def chunk_string(s, n):
    chunks = []
    last_index = len(s) - n
    for i in range(0, last_index + 1):
        chunks.append(s[i:i+n])
    return chunks
```

Comment: Nice, can you explain what the return line is doing?

Comment: Looks good. Is there any way I can have it print as a dictionary (without "Counter" coming before it)? Alternatively, is there a way to do this without importing from collections? Thanks.

Comment: @user3723011 You can convert it back into a dictionary if you want: `dict(counter)`.

Comment: @user3723011 And, if you don't want to import from `collections`, you can  use the methodology provided in `chunk_string` to iterate over the substrings in your current code.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Thank you!

Comment: @user3723011...*Do* accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically as the first posted answer by [Jared Goguen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2247550/jared-goguen), but in reply to OP's comment, for a possible way without importing a module:

```
>>> m
'CTAAAGTCAACCTTCGGTTGACCTTGAGGGTTCCCTAAGGGTTGGGGATGACCCTTGGGTCTAAAGTCAACCTTCGGTTGACCTTGAGGGTTCCCTAAGGGTT'
>>> l = [m[i:i+3] for i in range(len(m)-2)]
>>> 
>>> d = {}
>>> 
>>> for k in set(l):
        d[k] = l.count(k)


>>> d
{'AAG': 4, 'GGA': 1, 'AAA': 2, 'TAA': 4, 'AGG': 4, 'AGT': 2, 'GGG': 7, 'ACC': 5, 'CGG': 2, 'GGT': 7, 'TCC': 2, 'TGA': 5, 'CAA': 2, 'TGG': 2, 'GTC': 3, 'AAC': 2, 'ATG': 1, 'CTT': 5, 'TCA': 2, 'CCT': 7, 'CCC': 3, 'GTT': 6, 'TTG': 6, 'GAT': 1, 'GAC': 3, 'TCG': 2, 'GAG': 2, 'CTA': 4, 'TTC': 4, 'TCT': 1}
```

Or if you are a fan of one liners:

```
>>> d = {k:l.count(k) for k in set(l)}
```